# Add item sorted into a file in c

Tags: c, archive

I need to take a .txt file, and check the scores that exist in it, if my score is among the top 5, add my score and my name to the file, in the correct order. But in the way I did, the append, only adds at the end. Would there be any way to check the points that are in the file, to make the comparison?

Example: If my points are greater than 40, put my name and number of points first. Leaving the rest of the list sorted again.

pedro=40
joao=32
claudio=10
joao=2
Rick=0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char teste[1000], nome[20];
    int meuPonto=0;
    FILE *pontos;
    pontos = fopen("dados.txt", "r");

    if(pontos == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Pontuacao atual:\n");
    while(fgets(teste, 1000, pontos)){
        printf("%s\n", teste);
    }

    printf("Digite seu nome e seus pontos:\n");
    scanf("%s %i", nome, &meuPonto);

    fclose(pontos);
    pontos = fopen("dados.txt", "a");

    fprintf(pontos, "\n%s\n%d", nome, meuPonto);

    fclose(pontos);
}
```

The file can start at zero, but you have to save the score that was written.

Comment: If you need to put a new record in the middle of the file you can open a new file for writing. Read all records from `dados.txt` that should be before the new record and write them to the new file. Then write the new record to the new file. Read the rest of the records from `dados.txt` and write them to the new file. Close both files and rename the new file to `dados.txt`.

Comment: There's no way to insert in the middle of a file - you have to read the file and write a new one (or read it and then write the same one)

Comment: If you open a file with mode "a", all writes will go to the end of the file.

Comment: So, you want a 'Hall Of Fame' containing the highest 5 scores in the file? You would need to read at least some of the file into memory. I suggest to make an array of strings and read each record into it. Then, check to see if the score of the last entry is less than your new score. If not, there's nothing to do. Otherwise, you need to determine the position of the new score in the array, and shuffle the rows after it down one. Then input the new score and save the array.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise an array[MAX_SCORE] with empty lines.

Add your line to the array according to your score, array[your_score].

Read each line into array[line_score].
If you get duplicates (position not empty), append the line after a LF.

Finally, print the array (backwards) to a new file (or overwrite the old file). (skip empty lines).